# Input Assembly Bottleneck - HLSL

Tags: optimization, directx, hlsl, unreal-engine4

Im working on a voxelization shader, based on the single pass technique that's all the fuzz right now (https://developer.nvidia.com/content/basics-gpu-voxelization), and trying to optimize it. I ran nVidia NSIGHT, and got on the profiler a strange result.

Turns out the profiler says i'm input assembly bound.
Anyone has any idea how to handle this problem? What should I try to reduce?

For some more context, I'm working on real time GI for Unreal Engine 4, so I can't change the vertex format. Another thing that might be causing problems is the fact that I have to make a LOT of draw calls to voxelize (about 15K in some scenes), because the way I access the data in the engine.
That many draw calls could be causing the Input Assembly bottleneck?

For comparison, it takes like 7.65 ms on a GTX 970 for a complex scene (15K draw calls, 300x600x200 voxel grid)

Comment: What size is your vertex format (in bytes)?

Comment: About 4 - 5 float 4 if im correct.
The strange part is that rendering a shadow map, for the same objects with the exact same rendering code (only difference is no GS bound and of course the shaders themselves) takes 0.4 ms. My reasoning is that if I were bound by draw call count the difference should be smaller. It might be something with the Geometry Shader stage?

Comment: Geometry Shader does tend to be a bottleneck as none of the vendor implementations provide that stage with significant dedicated hardware resources. It works best when you have the same number of vertices going in and going out. For vertex formats, sticking with 32 byte or 64 byte total strides is the best for IA performance.